# Pandas fillna exception for 'NA' string

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

sample_file.txt

```
6|test|3|4
5|test||8
9|test|NA|12
```

Script

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample_file.txt', dtype='str', sep='|', names=['upc_cd', 'chr_typ', 'chr_vl','chr_vl_typ'])
df["chr_vl"].fillna("NOT AVLBL", inplace = True)
print(df)
```

Current output

```
upc_cd chr_typ     chr_vl chr_vl_typ
0      6    test          3          4
1      5    test  NOT AVLBL          8
2      9    test  NOT AVLBL         12
```

Required output

```
upc_cd chr_typ     chr_vl chr_vl_typ
0      6    test          3          4
1      5    test  NOT AVLBL          8
2      9    test         NA         12
```

Basically I need NA as it is in the output same time it should replace null values with the specific text 'NOT AVLBL'
Tried replace method as well, but couldn't get the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas read_csv functiomn already defines a set of strings that will be interpreted as NaNs when you load a csv file. Here you have the option to either extend that list with other strings or to also completely overwrite it. In your case you have to overwrite it, as NA is one of the default values used by pandas. To do so,
you could try something like

```py
df = pd.read_csv('sample_file.txt', dtype='str', sep='|',
                 names=['upc_cd', 'chr_typ', 'chr_vl','chr_vl_typ'],
                 na_values=[''], keep_default_na=False)
...
```

This will only interpret the empty string as NA as we have set `keep_default_na` to `False` and have only given `''` as a NA value with `na_values` argument.
If you want to learn more, have a look at the pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: This is indeed the correct way, but IMHO your answer could be better with some more explainations. If you add them, I will remove mine.

Comment: Yeah you are right thanks. I have added some text but feel free to just keep your answer too,